# Is the set of probability measures on a compact metric space (weak*-)closed?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

Let $(S,\mathcal B)$ be a compact metric space with the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra. Let $\mathcal M$ be the space of signed Borel measures and $\mathcal P \subset \mathcal M$ the set of probability measures on $(S,\mathcal B)$.

Now we say a sequence of measures $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $\mu_n\in \mathcal M$ for each $n$ converges in the weak*-topology to a measure $\mu \in \mathcal M$ if

(I) $\int fd\mu_n\overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}\int f d\mu$ for each countinuous and bounded function $f$ from $S$ to $\mathbb R$ that vanishes at infinity

(since $S$ is compact there aren't unbounded continuous $f$ anyways, and also "vanishing at infinity" has no meaning, hence this convergence coincides with the weak convergence of measures).

I know that for non-locally-compact sets $S$ the $\mathcal P$ is not closed in this topology. But several times I stumbled over the restriction **non-locally-compact** which makes me wonder how to show closedness of $\mathcal P$ in the compact case, i.e.

**Question:** Why can't there be a $\mu \in \mathcal M\setminus\mathcal P$ and a sequence of probability measures $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that (I) holds?

What I have tried:

If $\mu\not\in\mathcal P$ then either $\mu(S)\neq1$ or there is a set $A\in\mathcal B$ such that $\mu(A)<0$. In the former case choose $f\equiv1$ and see that (I) cannot be true.

In the latter case I think there has to be some open set $U$ such that $\mu(U)<0$ and then I can take a function $f$ that is strictly positive on $U$ and zero elsewhere, then (I) wouldn't hold either (left side would be zero or greater and right side negative). But I don't know if there really has to be such a set $U$.

I already asked a different question regarding the existence of such a set ([Obtaining the measure of a set from a limit of measures of open sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274289/obtaining-the-measure-of-a-set-from-a-limit-of-measures-of-open-sets)), but my approach there doesn't work.

Comment: There will be an open $U$ with $\mu(U) < 0$ (this follows from outer regularity of the measure) but it does not imply that a function $f$ strictly positive on $U$ and zero elsewhere must have negative integral, since $\mu$ could assign positive measure to some subset of $U$, and $f$ could be large on that subset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $A$ be any Borel set in $S$.  By Lusin's theorem, we can choose a sequence of continuous functions $f_m$ with $f_m \to 1_A$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.  Moreover, if we set $g_m = \max(\min(f_m, 1), 0)$ then $g_m$ is also continuous, $0 \le g_m \le 1$ and $g_m \to 1_A$ $\mu$-almost everywhere as well.

Since $\int g_m\,d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int g_m\,d\mu_n$, we have $\int g_m\,d\mu \ge 0$.  And by dominated convergence, $\lim_{m \to \infty} \int g_m \,d\mu =  \int \lim_{m \to \infty} g_m \,d\mu = \int \mathbf 1_A \,d\mu = \mu(A)$.  So $\mu(A) \ge 0$, and we conclude that $\mu$ is a positive measure.

Comment: The compactness of $S$ is only needed for Lusin's theorem, which also applies to spaces that are only **locally** compact, as a quick web search told me. Why doesn't your idea work for those spaces (or does it)?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, the same argument works in the locally compact case.

Comment: @NateEldredge Lusin's theorem and the dominated convergence theorem also work for signed measures? Implicitly, this is what you are doing.

Comment: @Satana: Lusin is valid for signed measures - you can apply the standard version of Lusin using the total variation measure $|\mu|$, and saying that the sequence converges $\mu$-a.e. is the same as saying $|\mu|$-a.e.  DCT is valid for signed measures when you suppose that the dominating function is $|\mu|$-integrable, which in this case it is.

Comment: @NateEldredge In general, are you saying that if $\mu$ is a signed measure and $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} f_m = f$ $\vert\mu\vert$-a.e. and $\vert f_m\vert \le g$ $\vert \mu\vert$-a.e. with $\int_{X}gd\vert\mu\vert <\infty$ then $\int_X f_md\mu\rightarrow \int_X fd\mu$? Obviously, in our case $g=1$, but how do we know that $\vert\mu\vert(X)<\infty$? Some consider the set of positive measures as a subset of the set of all signed measures (where you define a signed measure to take at most one of $\infty$ or $-\infty$). So it doesn't seem like $\vert \mu\vert(X)<\infty$ in general.

Comment: @NateEldredge Or are we implicitly taking $\mathcal{M}$ to be the space of Borel signed measures of **finite total variation**, and not the space of **all** signed measures?

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry for all the comments. I see your first point. We have $\vert \mu\vert = \mu^+ + \mu^-$ where $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-$ is a Hahn decomposition of $\mu$. Then since $\vert \mu\vert(E) = 0$ implies $\mu^+(E)= \mu^-(E)=0$, we can get a DCT for each $\int f_md\mu^{\pm}$ and piece everything together. (Correct?) But it still seems like my second point could be an issue if $\mu$ does not have finite total variation (equiv., if $\vert \mu\vert(X)=\infty$). So I still have the question as to whether $\mathcal{M}$ is the space of all Borel signed measure of finite total variation?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming here that "signed measure" means "finite signed measure", which implies that it has finite total variation.  That is the more common definition, in my experience, and it's the only way for the weak-* convergence defined in the question to make sense.  (Your DCT proof is correct, by the way.)