# Radon probability measures are weak star closed in all complex radon measures.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact space and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the set of all Radon probability measures on $X$, which is a subset of $M(X)$ (the space of all complex Radon measures). The latter space obtains a weak$^*$-topology through the duality $M(X) \cong C(X)^*$. I want to show that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is weak$^*$-closed in $M(X)$.

So, take a net ${\mu_\alpha}$ in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with $\lim_\alpha \mu_\alpha = \mu \in M(X)$ where the limit is taken in the weak$^*$-topology. Explicitely, this means that $\lim_\alpha \int_X f d \mu\alpha = \int_X f d \mu$ for all $f \in C(X)$. Is there a fast way to see that $\mu$ is a positive measure?

Comment: A Radon measure $\mu$ is positive if and only if $\int f\,d\mu\geq 0$ for all positive $f\in C(X)$.

Comment: I've been thinking of this quite recently. MaoWao's comment is the key here, and a proof of this claim is given by Nate elderedge in this post, using Lusin's theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277450/is-the-set-of-probability-measures-on-a-compact-metric-space-weak-closed